# Blender cloud for speeding up physics simulation

Tags: rendering, physics, cloth-simulation

I am working on cloth simulation, and I have a lot of test-and-edit cycles to do. But on my machine the test cycles - where the simulation is baked - takes too much time.
It's a simple simulation, but there are lots of frames to bake, with a highly subdivided mesh. I don't need distributed computing. I just need more processing power and RAM - so basically just blender running on a high performance server; and I don't own a server space (yet). I'd also prefer not to edit my scripts or change the work process in some other way. If need be, I can do it though.
Is there any such online/cloud based solution for blender? Blender Cloud seems to offer something else entirely.

Comment: I think maybe the data transfer between computers would then become your bottleneck.  Also, baking simulations writes a lot of data to the hard-drive does it not?  I think it does... Anyways, if that's what is slowing you down, a faster processor and more RAM may not help much, you would need faster HD access.   Hard-drive access is usually going to be at least 200 times slower than the computer's main system bus, it's a huge bottleneck when reading and writing assets.  Well, good-luck. :)

Comment: @MarcClintDion My bake cache is entirely in RAM actually, because I think writing it to disk will be much slower. There won't be any data transfer. The baking and caching can happen on the server, using server's resources - processor, RAM/Disk etc . I can then do what I want with the cache. I can download the cache and do the rendering on my machine or somewhere else. The slowest part is the baking, and that has no interaction with user. So that can happen on some server...

Comment: @MarcClintDion In most cases baking is so expensive you don't need to worry about anything else becoming a bigger bottle neck..

Comment: @sanjeevmk We've decided that questions asking for blender-related resources are off-topic of the most part: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/341/599